# Is it healthy for no frost fridge to have water in ice cube forms?

Tags: freezing, refrigerator, water, frozen

It's said that we should close liquids when we put them into fridge that has no frost system (no ice formation in the freezer).Or ice will appear and the fridge will not serve that long. 
At the same time there are forms for ice cubes in my fridge, in the upper shelf of the freezer.
They're open, so I supposed to pour water and leave this water exposed to the freezer.
I think if I'll use them I'll harm my fridge, I'll have to defrost it or may be even fix it.

Comment: Did the ice cube trays come with the freezer? It would be very strange to supply an accessory that shouldn't be used

Comment: @Chris H yes it did. But, you know, some people fix cars the others say my never been broken, perhaps because they use them with different intencity.

Answer (score 2):

In short, it's within design tolerance.

[Frost-free freezers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-defrost) work by generating a periodic warm-up phase which lets any ice melt. The water is then drained to near the heat exchanger, which will then evaporate it off outside the freezer body.

Ice cube trays don't generate sufficient additional water vapour within the freezer compartment to compromise this process - except in the runners directly surrounding the trays themselves, which for some bizarre reason don't seem to ever stay as frost-free as the rest of the compartment;)

Comment: Why they don't in the freezer, but would do in the main department?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Don't do what in the freezer? & what 'main compartment'?

Comment: Why ice is not going to form in the freezer because of cubes, but on the other hand it would form in a coldstore. Why there is such a difference?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand what you are asking. What do you consider to be a 'coldstore'? You're adding new terms without sufficient explanation as to what you need.

Comment: by coldstore I mean the bigger compartment, where you'd put a grilled chicken and a lemon juice. I don't understand why liquid is bad for the bigger compartment, but not going to do anything to the freezer.

Comment: You've completely lost me now. Who told you you can't put liquid in a fridge? Of course it makes sense to put a lid on to prevent evaporation or spillage, but what makes you think it would be 'bad' for the fridge?

Comment: That's what I'm talking about - evaporation. As I know it's necessary to not create humid air in such kind of fridge.

Comment: **What** about evaporation? Fridges are designed to stay cool & dry. that's their job. Old fridges with just an ice box in the top corner don't, but any modern fridge cycles the air to prevent condensation in the fridge part & ice in the freezer part.